# Unable to change Windows 10 display language on a domain

Tags: windows, language, domain

My laptop is an HP ProBook 450 G7 which is connected to a domain.

When I log into a local PC account on it I can change the Windows display language without a problem, but when I log into a domain account on it I am unable to change the Windows display language and I don't know why. When I try it on another PC it works properly. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Here is a video: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AscLp30sa9jAtFK2sPbj6zUIAEm-?e=sBevnH